# using of glviewport() in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I read this [tutorial](http://www.computaholics.in/2015/05/circle-drawing-in-opengl-using-mid.html) and I execute it correctly.

However, I wanted to apply some changes. The first change was to see a different view of that circle, for example showing just the 1/4 of the circle. I know this is done by glViewPort(parameters). However, after changing the parameters, nothing happens. I have checked many forums to figure out why this problem occurs, but I couldn't figure out anything.

Can someone explain me more on this and how to use it? (To understand where the problem happens)

This is the code (Which is originally written on that [tutorial](http://www.computaholics.in/2015/05/circle-drawing-in-opengl-using-mid.html))

Code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init(void)
{
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  //glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,200.0);
  //glViewport(0, 0, 250, 250);
}


void setPixel(GLint x,GLint y)
{
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glVertex2i(x,y);
  glEnd();
}

void Circle(){

  int xCenter=100,yCenter=100,r=50;
  int x=0,y=r;
  int p = 3/2 - r;
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f( 1 ,0, 0);
  while(x<=y){
    setPixel(xCenter+x,yCenter+y);
    setPixel(xCenter+y,yCenter+x);
    setPixel(xCenter-x,yCenter+y);
    setPixel(xCenter+y,yCenter-x);
    setPixel(xCenter-x,yCenter-y);
    setPixel(xCenter-y,yCenter-x);
    setPixel(xCenter+x,yCenter-y);
    setPixel(xCenter-y,yCenter+x);

    if (p<0)
  p += (2*x)+3;
    else {
 p += (2*(x-y))+5;
 y -= 1;
    }
    x++;
  }

  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);


    glutCreateWindow("My Circl2e");
    init();

    glViewport(0,0,250,250);
    //glLoadIdentity();

    glutDisplayFunc(Circle);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

p.s: In some examples I see they use setWindow(parameters) before using glViewPort(parameters). but setWindow() needs  library which is not available for ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default GLUT reshape function calls `glViewport()` with the window size. From the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html):

> If a reshape callback is not registered for a window or NULL is passed to glutReshapeFunc (to deregister a previously registered callback), the default reshape callback is used. This default callback will simply call glViewport(0,0,width,height) on the normal plane (and on the overlay if one exists).

Since you call `glViewport()` so early, the window will be shaped after you make your call, overriding the viewport you specified.

You either need to register your own reshape function, and call `glViewport()` with your desired viewport parameters there, or call `glViewport()` at the start of your `Circle()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I called glViewport() at start of my circle() function and I saw some changes happen. The thing is that it now just changes the size of the circle. For example the circle that I see if I set glviewPort(0, 0, 200, 200) is twice bigger than when I set it to glViewport(0, 0, 100). What I want to do is just to see a part of a circle, for example half of it. Can you help me on this? Thank you